# getting a value inside a code block to function return in swift

Tags: parse-platform, swift2

I am working with parse, I am trying to return row.count of a table and output it to a label.text.

```
func numberOfPostedJobsCount() -> Int{
    var postsCount: Int?
    var query = PFQuery(className: "Post")
    if let user = PFUser.currentUser() {
        query.whereKey("user", equalTo: user)
    }
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]?, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            //query succeeded
            print("\(objects?.count)")
        } else {
            print("\(error)")
        }
    }

    return postsCount!
}
```

The code inside viewDidLoad() is

```
numberOfPostedJobs.text = String(numberOfPostedJobsCount())
```

error : fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Edit 1: I tried adding a public or private variable but it didn't work.

```
func numberOfPostedJobsCount() -> (Int) {
    var num1: Int = 0
    var query = PFQuery(className: "Post")
    if let user = PFUser.currentUser() {
        query.whereKey("user", equalTo: user)
    }
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]?, error) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            //query succeeded
            print("\(objects?.count)")
            num1 = (objects?.count)!
            print(num1)
        } else {
            print("\(error)")
        }
    }

    return num1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `postsCount` is declared but never be initialized, so it's `nil` when you unwrap it.

Be aware that the function `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` works asynchronously, that means the block is called always **after** the return statement. In this block you have to update your data source and/or the UI.

**Edit:**

Return `Void` from your function and use a completion handler for example

```
func numberOfPostedJobsCount(completion: (Int) -> ()) {
  var query = PFQuery(className: "Post")
  if let user = PFUser.currentUser() {
    query.whereKey("user", equalTo: user)
  }
  query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]?, error) -> Void in

    if error == nil {
      //query succeeded
      print("\(objects?.count)")
      let num1 = (objects?.count)!
      completion(num1)
    } else {
      print("\(error)")
       completion(0)
    }
  }
}
```

You call the function this way

```
numberOfPostedJobsCount() { (postsCount) -> () in
  numberOfPostedJobs.text = String(postsCount)
}
```

Comment: I added a variable as a data source inside the function to update. Still doesn't work. I updated my post

Comment: The function will return always 0 because of the asynchronous behavior of the block.

Comment: thanks! I should educate myself more about functions with completions. works beautifully!

Comment: how do I call this function inside another function? I need to return the value to tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int

Comment: `numberOfRowsInSection` is supposed to return the number of elements in the array calling `<array>.count` directly. Update the array and call `reloadData()`

Comment: the data source is inside the function with completion I created.

Comment: Declare the data source variable on class level as an empty array and populate/update the array in the completion handler

Comment: I succeeded adding it to an array, my proble is that I can't add the createdAt(NSDate) from parse to the array(PFObject). I tried converting it to NSDate but it returns " Cannot convert value of type 'NSDate!' to expected argument type 'PFObject'"

Comment: I'm not that familiar with `parse`

Answer (score 0):

You can use semaphores to make a asynchronous method to work synchronously:

A Sample method for your problem statement

```
func test()->Int {
    var postsCount: Int?
    let sema:dispatch_semaphore_t = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)) { () -> Void in
        postsCount = 100
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema)
    }

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
    return postsCount!
}
```

for above code:

```
func numberOfPostedJobsCount() -> Int{
var postsCount: Int?
var query = PFQuery(className: "Post")
let sema:dispatch_semaphore_t = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)
if let user = PFUser.currentUser() {
    query.whereKey("user", equalTo: user)
}
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]?, error) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        //query succeeded
        postsCount = objects?.count
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema)
        print("\(objects?.count)")
    } else {
        postsCount = 0
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema)
        print("\(error)")
    }
}
dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
return postsCount!
}
```

Comment: how do I implement this in my code, I tried putting findObject block inside dispatch_async block.

Comment: I tried your way but it app got stuck when I call the function in viewDidLoad()